# using youtube api to load mutable videos by id

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have been trying to make a site that has mutable iframes with a different video loaded by id but cant get my for loop to work to load in the ids this is the script i have. the ids there are just the first lot to test it works.

```
  var ids = ["ztK0rBXfI3s", "62Z-rITm0kk"];
  var p=0;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  for(p<ids.length; p++){
    var player[p];
    player[p] = new YT.Player('ytplayer[p]', {
    height: '390',
    width: '640',
    videoId: 'ids[p]',
  }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make sure you have `<div>`s with the proper ids on them. These `<div>`s will be replaced with `<iframe>` Elements. Then learn loops:

```
var pre = onload;
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre();
function YTVideosInit(elementIdsArray, videoIdsArray){
  var ytp = [];
  for(var i=0,l=elementIdsArray.length; i<l; i++){
    var player = new YT.Player(elementIdsArray[i], {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: videoIdsArray[i]
    });
    ytp.push(player);
  }
  return ytp;
}
var players = YTVideosInit(['id1', 'id2'],  ['ztK0rBXfI3s', '62Z-rITm0kk']);
// players is now an Array of players
}
```